# NodeJs - Nested Functions with a for loop which does not work properly inside

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, callback, nested

today my question is actually about the problem which happens due to loop which is not working properly but anyway, i am quite open to ideas if i have issues about designing.

```js
app.post('/admin/earning/:multiplier', function (req, res) {

  var multiplier = req.params.multiplier;

  var now = new Date();

  var List=[];

  var dailySaving;

  //  Getting the investors emails(key) from the collection.

  db.getInvestorsFromValidatedInvests(function(err,result){

    if(err){console.log(err);}

    console.log(result);

    List = result;

    console.log('Inside the List scope'+List[0]);

    for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++){

      db.returnTotalInvestingfromValidatedInvests(List[i],function(err,rst){

      if(err){console.log(err);}

      console.log(rst);

      var dailySaving = ((rst*multiplier)/100);

      console.log('Daily Savings which is going to be added is that  :  ' +dailySaving);

      console.log(List[i]);

      db.multiplyInvestAndAddSavings(List[i],dailySaving,function(err,rest){

        if(err){console.log(err);}

        console.log(rest);

      });

    });

    }

    });

  res.json('Going to be Prepared...');
});
```

Here i am sharing you each of these database functions :

First function gets the owner e-mails from db and returns an array and then, i want to do some operations with each elements of this array and i decided to use for loop but it does not work properly.

```js
Db.prototype.getInvestorsFromValidatedInvests = function(callback){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@ds9999.mlab.com:99986/xxxxxx", function (err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
    db.collection('validatedInvests').distinct("owner",function(err,result){
      if(err){console.log(err); callback(err,null);}
      callback(null,result);
    });
    db.close();
});
}
```

```js
Db.prototype.returnTotalInvestingfromValidatedInvests = function(owner,callback){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@ds09999.mlab.com:9996/aslanservices", function (err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
    db.collection('validatedInvests').find({"owner":owner}).toArray(function(err,result){
      var sum=0;
      if(err){console.log(err); callback(err,null);}
      for(var j=0;j<result.length;j++){
        sum+=parseInt(result[j].amount); 
      }
      callback(null,sum);
    });
    db.close();
});
}
```

```js
Db.prototype.multiplyInvestAndAddSavings = function(owner,amount,callback){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxxx@ds99996.mlab.com:39996/aslanservices", function (err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
    console.log('Db talking amount is'+amount);
    db.collection('investClients').updateOne({"email":owner},
    {
      $inc : {
        "savingsAccount" : +amount
      },
      
    },
    {
      upsert : true
    }
    ,function(err,result){
      if(err){callback(err,null);}
      callback(null,result);
    });
    db.close();
});
}
```

The output is  :

Inside the List Scope >  lets say blablabla@gmail.com

220

Daily Savings which is going to be added is that : 8.8

undefined

150

Daily Savings which is going to be added is that : 6

undefined

Db talking amount is 8.8

Db talking amount is 6

Expected ouput is that  :

220

Daily Savings which is going to be added is that : 8.8

blablabla@gmail.com

Db talking amount is 8.8

150

Daily Savings which is going to be added is that : 6

secondblablabla@gmail.com

Db talking amount is 6

Comment: The loop "does not work properly": Despite the code, please be more precise: How does it behave / how should it work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not a code dump and vague description.

Comment: Okay wait a second i will add expected and normal output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a for loop with async functionality inside. Let me try to explain:

```
for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++){
    // first iteration, the variable i is 
}
```

now the first async function gets executed:

```
db.returnTotalInvestingfromValidatedInvests(List[i],function(err,rst){
     /*this is an async callback which will be executed in a 
     different context in a later time, when the response is received*/
}
```

So what happens is the main execution where the for loop is being executed doesn't wait for the response (since async) from the above function, and moves forward incrementing the variable `i` executing the next iteration with your function `db.returnTotalInvestingfromValidatedInvests` and it onwards.
Very soon the whole for loop is ended whether or not all or any of your responses have arrived.

The reason you're getting `undefined` is because at the end of the loop the variable `i` has value of `List.length` which means that it is accessing `List[list.length]`. Which will always be undefined since the max index is always `length-1`.

**Summary:** You will have to keep a track of the element at `List[i]` somehow so that when the final (nested) function's async callback is triggered, you can update the correct element. Some people do that by creating hashes, some do it by converting their logic to synchronous in terms of loop.

**Advice:**

Try logging out `i` in each of the function callbacks to see the variable being changed quickly.

Hope the explanation helps :)

**As requested, here's one way to do it:**

```
  function onInvestsDone(err, obj){
    if(err!=null){
      // something went wrong
    }
    else{
      // do anything here with your final response
    }
  }

  for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++){
    returnInvests(List, i, onInvestsDone);    
  }



  function returnInvests(listArray, index, cb){
    db.returnTotalInvestingfromValidatedInvests(listArray[index],function(err,rst){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        cb(err);  // call callback with error
      }
      console.log(rst);
      var dailySaving = ((rst*multiplier)/100);
      console.log('Daily Savings which is going to be added is that  :  ' +dailySaving);
      console.log(listArray[index]);
      db.multiplyInvestAndAddSavings(listArray[index],dailySaving,function(err,rest){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          cb(err);  // call callback with error
        }
        console.log(rest);
        // successfully done everything
        cb(null, rest);
      });

    });
  }
```

Comment: I understood your point, it does not wait for the response and keeps incrementing "i" . Thank you so much for clarifying the reason behind that, i still have confusion about how to provide a solution that waits the response and moves forward with precise data. Can you  help me with that ? I mean can you give me an example of what you have advised?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll add to the answer

Comment: Updated the answer with the snippet. Don't forget to vote up ;)